# Auto-refresh image library contents in web part

Tags: ajax, picture-library, development

I am loading an image into a `<div>` tag from an image library. I want to to refresh this `<div>` tag every 10sec so that new images uploaded can be seen.

Is there any good solution?

Comment: @abhik: Use the backtick character if you want to show HTML tags in your posts (check the formatting reference when you write your question). Thanks for joining SharePoint Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest

1. Make you webpart ajax based i.e. put that inside a Update Panel.
2. Use the ASP.net Timer control that can initiate a post back and on onload you can update your image property.

more on timer control here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.interval.aspx
more on update panel with timer control:
http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this differs from your image rotator question. I'll provide the same suggestion, a pure JavaScript (no jQuery) solution:

http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Image-Rotator.aspx

It only works for authenticated users. For anonymous access, you'd need to use a different data source.